# Speed change command fails when audio stream is not present in video - ffmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, video-editing

I am trying to change speed of the video that does not contain audio stream via below command

```
String[]{"ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", orginalFile, "-threads", "5", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex", "[0:v]setpts=0.50*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "[a]", "-b", "2097k", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", destinationFile};
```

**Command fails stating that video does not have audio stream**. *So, do I need to check whether audio stream is present in the video or is there something I can do in this scenario?*

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the video before running the command (using ffmpeg -i )
You will get the information in the vk.log.
Parse it, and see if you have audio.
Then run the correct command.

Answer (score 2):

Option `-map a` only accept video with audio stream, There are some video have not audio. you need use `-map 0`. Solution for two case is you use `?`:

```
 -map [a?]
```

The `?` teels ffmpeg to only map the stream if it exists.

Comment: Thanks @phongvan It does not work here is what I tried:
String[]{"ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", orginalFile, "-threads", "5", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex", "[0:v]setpts=0.50*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "[a?]", "-b", "2097k", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", destinationFile};

Comment: Could you try: String[]{"ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", orginalFile, "-threads", "5", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex", "[0:v]setpts=0.50*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "0:a?", "-b", "2097k", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", destinationFile}; ?

Comment: that won't work. try ` String[]{"-ss", lastTime, "-i", selectedVideoPath, "-t", now,  "-filter:v", "setpts=0.5*PTS","-strict", "-2", videoPath};`

Answer (score 2):

If you use stream-specific filterchains, you use should be able to process all files - with or without audio.

Use

```
String[]{"ffmpeg", "-y", "-i", originalFile, "-threads", "5",
         "-map", "0:v", "-map", "0:a?",
         "-vf setpts=0.50*PTS", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-b:v", "2097k",
         "-af atempo=2.0", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050",
         "-strict", "experimental", destinationFile}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya! It's not working, giving error at **"0:a?"** and the error is 'Does not match any streams'

Comment: Ok, it's available in v2.8 or later, or in a nightly build from July '15 onwards.

Comment: Actually I am using a library which is derived from ffmpeg. details [link](https://github.com/dirgautomo/ffmpeg4android)